# How do I load images of all playing cards?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to load images of all playing cards using for loops. However, the `pygame.image.load` comes as a string `'CK': "pygame.image.load('cards/CK.png')"` instead of `'CK': pygame.image.load('cards/CK.png')`.

Any suggestions how I can have the value in the string rather than the string itself, in the dictionary?

```
self.suits = {'S':'spades', 'H':'hearts', 'D':'diamonds', 'C': 'clubs'}
self.values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9,
               'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}
cardpngs = {}
for suit in self.suits:
    for symbol in self.values.keys():
        card_name = f"{suit}{symbol}"
        folder_name = f"pygame.image.load('cards/{card_name}.png')"
        cardpngs[card_name] = folder_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue seems to be here

```
folder_name = f"pygame.image.load('cards/{card_name}.png')"
```

this is just a string, you want to load the actual image so you should do this instead:

```
folder_name = pygame.image.load(f'cards/{card_name}.png')
```